# An inequality involving the Gamma function

Tags: inequality, gamma-function

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ,$\forall x\ge1$ seems to hold the following inequality:
$$\Gamma(x)+\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\le\Gamma\left(1+x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ where the sign of equality holds only for $x=1.$
How can it be proven? Thanks.

Comment: Using $\Gamma(1/x)<x$ for $x>1$ may help : see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) and the Laurent expansion at $1$. Note that your relation is weak and should hold too with the addition replaced by the product at the left.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I guess it holds also replacing $\Gamma(x)$ with $x\Gamma(x)$ in the left.

Comment: Well since this is $\Gamma(1+x)\cdots$

Comment: Proving your inequality (for values of $x$ near $1$) doesn't appear that easy after closer examination sorry... (making this problem much more interesting! +1). Perhaps that more sophisticated methods like these proposed by Alzer in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705003742) will be of more value. I'll try to provide a solution tomorrow (if nobody else proposes one...).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: The inequality seems to have been proven by Donald Kershaw in a private communication, but I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of this (rather non-trivial for $x\approx 1$) inequality was provided by Jameson in $2012$ in ['An inequality for the gamma function conjectured by D. Kershaw'](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-06-18.pdf).
Concerning the product a proof is in Giordano and Laforgia's [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700006592).

Comment: Raymond, I was wondering if you can take a look at the question I asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179266/inequality-for-incomplete-gamma-function