# How that $\int_0^x\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^b+s^a}{2}\right) dtds \leq \int_0^x\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^a+s^b}{2}\right)dtds$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to show the following inequality
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^b+s^a}{2}\right)\,dt\,ds \leq \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^a+s^b}{2}\right)\,dt\,ds
\end{align}

where $0<a<b$ and all $x>0$.

I learned This is the inequality from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179266/inequality-for-incomplete-gamma-function). However, I was not able to follow the proof.

Comment: Order os integration does not match the other post you mentioned

Comment: @Math-fun I substituted $(s,t) \to (t,s)$. Is it wrong?

Comment: This is hard: the usual tricks don't seem to work on it.

Comment: @kimchilover It was claimed that this follows from monotonicity of the exponential, here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179266/inequality-for-incomplete-gamma-function

Comment: I know that's what it says, but I don't follow that argument.

Comment: Lisa, I misunderstood your nested integration formula, and worked on what I called $B/A$ when I should have worked on $A/B$, as was clear from the very original post & answer. I deleted my erroneous answer.  But I don't see how to prove the result.  In part because  $t^a<t^b$ if $t>1$ but $t^a>t^b$ if $t<1$.  Sorry about the confusion this might have caused.  I'll post again only when & if I am absolutely sure.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks a lot for your afford. I also tried for some time to show this, but have been stuck for a while.  Anyway, thanks and let me know if you have any updates.

Comment: I think I have a proof, but it has several pieces.  I should have a post in a day or so, if it holds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reformuated by Jack D'Aurizio, this boils down to showing that $$\int_0^x e^{-t^a/2}\,dt\space  \int_0^\infty e^{-t^b/2} \,dt\le \int_0^x e^{-t^b/2}\,dt\space  \int_0^\infty e^{-t^a/2}\,dt,$$ equivalently $A(x) B(\infty) \le B(x) A(\infty)$ or $$ R(x) = \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} \le \frac{A(\infty)}{B(\infty)} = R(\infty) $$ where $A(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^a/2}\,dt$ and $B(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^b/2}\,dt.$ Here $0<a<b$ and $0<x$.

Here is a sketch of a proof; details will be filled in below.  I have tried to number the steps for future reference.  I am sure a more direct or thematically satisfying argument exists.

Step 1: For $x\ge 1$ it suffices to check that $\alpha(x)/\beta(x)\ge R(\infty),$ where $\alpha(x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-t^a/2}\,dt$ and $\beta(x)=\int_x^\infty e^{-t^b/2}\,dt.$ Step 2: A simple argument (which is what D'Aurizio probably had in mind originally) shows that $\alpha(x)/\beta(x)$ increases on $[1,\infty)$, leaving the case $\alpha(1)/\beta(1)\ge R(\infty)$ (that is, that $R(1)\le R(\infty)$ to be checked by a side argument given in Step 3.

Step 4: For the range $[0,1]$ we check first that $R(0) = a/b\le R(\infty),$ and then in Step 5 analyse the critial points of $R$ in $[0,1].$ Let $r = (a/b)^{1/(b-a)},$ clearly $r \in [0,1].$ If $x\le r $ and $R'(x) = 0,$ then $R''(x)\le0$ but if $x\ge r$, and $R'(x)=0$ then $R''(x)\ge 0$.  Step 6: Side calculations show that $R$ is decreasing near $0$ and increasing at $1$; these imply that $R$ has exactly one local minimum and no interior local maxima in $[0,1],$ and hence $\max_{[0,1]} R(x) = \max(R(0), R(1))$.  Which is already covered in Steps 3 and 4.

Only step 3 gives me pleasure.

Here are the details.

STEP 1:
Since $A(x)+\alpha(x)=A(\infty),$ etc, so $R(x)\le R(\infty)$ translates into
$\alpha(x)/\beta(x)\ge R(\infty).$

STEP 2:
For $1\le x\le t$, the inequality $x^a-t^a \ge x^b - t^b$ holds.  It obviously holds when $t=x$ and since $(\partial/\partial t) (t^b-t^a)\ge 0,$ it holds for $t\ge x$ as well.  The sign of $(\alpha(x)/\beta(x))'$ is the same as the sign of $$\alpha'(x)\beta(x)-\alpha(x)\beta'(x) = \int_x^\infty ( -e^{-x^a/2}e^{-t^b/2} + e^{-x^b/2}e^{-t^a/2})\,dt.$$  (Since $x$ is the lower limit of integration, $\alpha'<0$, etc.) On multiplying by $\exp(x^a/2+x^b/2)$ the integrand is seen to have the same sign as $ e^{x^a/2}e^{-t^a/2} - e^{x^b/2}e^{-t^b/2},$ which is evidently non-negative.  Hence $\alpha/\beta$ is increaing on $[1,\infty). $

STEP 3:
Here we write $\alpha(1) = 2^{1/a}\Gamma(1/a,1/2),$ $\beta(1) = 2^{1/b}\Gamma(1/b,1/2),$ and $R(\infty) = 2^{1/a-1/b} \Gamma(1/a)/\Gamma(1/b),$ and the reqirement that $\alpha(1)/\beta(1)\ge R(\infty)$ follows from the observation that $\Gamma(s,1/2)/\Gamma(s)$ is increasing in $s$.  This follows from the convolution semigroup property of the family of Gamma distribution functions: if $G_s$ and $G_h$ are   independent, Gamma distributed random variables, with parameters $s>0$ and $h>0$ repectively, then  $G_s+G_h$ is Gamma distributed with parameter $t=s+h$.  The application of this to our case is that $P(G_s>1/2) = \Gamma(s,1/2)/\Gamma(s)$.  Since the event $[G_s > 1/2]$ is a subset of $[G_t>1/2] = [G_s+G_h>1/2]$, we have $ \Gamma(s,1/2)/\Gamma(s) =P(G_s>1/2)\le P(G_t>1/2) = \Gamma(t,1/2)/\Gamma(t).$ Take $s=1/b$ and $t=1/a$ to finish the argument that $\alpha(1)/\beta(1)\ge R(\infty).$

STEP 4:
Here we write $A(x) = 2^{1/a} \gamma(1/a,x^a/2),$ etc, and appeal to A\&S 6.5.29 to write $A(x) = a x (1 - x^a/(2(a+1)) + o(x^a))$ as $x\to 0$, etc, so $R(0) = a/b$ and (since $x^b = o(x^a)$, $R$ is decreasing near $0$.  We now show $a/b \le R(\infty) = 2^{1/a - 1/b}\Gamma(1/a) /\Gamma(1/b) $ by observing that the function $s\mapsto s 2^s \Gamma(s) = 2^s \Gamma(s+1)$ is increasing.  Its logarithmic derivative is $ \log 2 + \psi(1+s)$.  Since $\psi$ is increasing, it suffices to check this at $s=0$, viz., that $\log 2 + \psi(1) \ge 0$.  But $\psi(1) = -\gamma,$ so $\log 2 + \psi(1)\approx 0.6931 - 0.5772 > 0.$

STEP 5:
At a critical point of $R$, we have $A'B=AB'$ and $R'' = (A'' B - A B'')/B^4.$ Hence, at a critical point of $R$, the sign of $R''$ is the same as the sign of $A'' /A' - B''/B'.$  This last expression is $bx^{b-1}/2 - ax^{a-1}/2$, which is negative if $x<r$ and positive if $r>r$, where $r=(a/b)^{1/(b-a)}.$

STEP 6: We saw at the beginning of Step 4 that $R$ decreases near $0$.  The sign of $R'(1)$ is that of $A'(1)B(1)-A(1)B'(1)$.  But $A'(1) = B'(1) = \exp(-1/2)$, so the sign of $R'(1)$ is that of $B(1)-A(1) = \int_0^1 \exp(-t^b/2)-\exp(-t^a/2)\,dt.$  Since $t^a> t^b$ on $(0,1)$, the integrand is positive a.e. and hence $R'(1)>0$.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, went over your proof.  So, how come the proof is so long and there is no simple argument?

Comment: You are welcome. One reason its so long & complex is that I wrote up the first argument I believed, without taking time to see what was really going on and to see if there was a simpler way to think about the problem.  (I was exhausted, and glad to be able to stop.)  One difficulty I had was the seeming need to continually introduce new symbols: $A(x)$ and $\alpha(x)$, for example. And continually having to remember that sometimes $\sqrt x < x$ and sometimes $x<\sqrt x$.

Comment: Great thank you for your insight.